# What's a good low-impact way for me to preserve this expensive data structure?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm working with mature production code written using Java EE.  To deal with an unusual data condition, I've inserted a sanity check that works, but is adding some unnecessary cost.  The architecture works like this:

1. On Page 1, user selects an item from a list and clicks the Go button.
2. An Ajax call to Page 1's view-scoped controller bean creates a Big Expensive Data Object (BEDO), which it then sanity checks to make sure it's valid.
3. If the BEDO is valid, Page 1 forwards itself via Javascript to Page 2.
4. Page 2's view-scoped backing bean creates a new copy of the BEDO, identical to the one used for the sanity check.

I'm creating the same BEDO twice, and simply throwing away the first one.  I'd like to figure out a solution that wastes fewer processing cycles.

So my question is, what's the best low-impact way of getting the BEDO from Page 1's controller bean to Page 2's backing bean?  Giving Page 1's controller access to the backing bean doesn't work; because Page 2's backing bean is view-scoped, it gets created anew when the user actually gets sent to Page 2.

I could change the scope of Page 2's backing bean, but I'd rather not.  Because this is mature production code, I'm very wary of introducing regression errors.  That's what I mean by "low-impact"; I don't want to fool around with the existing architecture any more than I have to.

Comment: See if you can reduce the overhead by using Flyweight: A flyweight is an object that minimizes memory use by sharing as much data as possible with other similar objects

Comment: @Pangea:  Thanks for showing me an interesting concept, but unfortunately it's not a good fit for my needs in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the winner is ... Flash Scope.

With this on one end:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("bedo", bedo);
```

And this on the other:

```
Object bedoObj = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("bedo");
if (bedoObj != null && bedoObj instanceof BigExpensiveDataObject) {
   ...
```

... I get exactly the behavior I'm looking for.